# signing report on debug

Tags: android, debugging

I am using my android device for debugging instead of emulator. I did connect my project to Firebase. And after that when I run project for debug, app is not running in my android device. And in the project, my device name is showing as disabled. there is an error message when mouse over on device name that is - Not applicable for the "Project Name[signingReport]" configuration. Can anyone help me please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79nvu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have selected "Signing Report" on the left dropdown, click on it and select the item with your project name and the Android icon as shown in the image below.

[image]